# Installing 32bit libraries with dpkg < 1.16

Tags: x86, 64-bit, debian, libraries, dpkg

---

I'm using Debian 6 with dpkg 1.15.
In dpkg 1.15 multiarch support is not implemented. There is also no backport for 1.16.

My problem is that I have an application(Arma II server) that needs a 32bit version of libsdtc++6 to start. But as dpkg --print-architecture shows "amd64" only and dpkg --add-architecture is not accessible in Debian 6, I haven't found any way to add the libraries.

Is there any possibility to add the necessary 32bit libraries for the application?

Comment: You might have to either manually search for a pre-built 32-bit version of libstdc++6, or grab the source and build it yourself on a 32-bit machine

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem now. For everybody else having problems with Arma II servers on Debian 6: The server needs a more recent version of the libstdc++6 32bit library. You can get this library by either adding the testing repo to your sources.list and upgrade your libstdc++6 or by manually compiling a newer version of gcc which also includes the necessary library.